# SQL/HIVE - How do I query from a horizontal output to vertical output?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a query that returns two rows with the information needed

```
SELECT src_file_dt, a, b ,c FROM my_table WHERE src_file_dt IN ('1531675040', '1531675169');
```

it will return:

```
src_file_dt | a | b | c  
1531675040  | 2 | 6 | 9  
1531675169  | 8 | 2 | 0
```

Now, I need the data in the following layout, how do I get it like this output:

```
fields | prev (1531675040) | curr (1531675169)
a      |   2               | 8
b      |   6               | 2
c      |   9               | 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be easier way to achieve that.
I've build results using `explode` function and selecting separately data for prev and next columns:

```
select t1.keys, t1.vals as prev, t2.vals as next from (
SELECT explode(map('a', a, 'b', b, 'c',c)) as (keys, vals)
FROM my_table 
WHERE src_file_dt = '1531675040'
) t1, 
(
SELECT explode(map('a', a, 'b', b, 'c',c)) as (keys, vals)
FROM my_table 
WHERE src_file_dt = '1531675169'
) t2
where t1.keys = t2.keys
;
```

Comment: wow this actually worked. I would have never guess this one. Thanks!